# How can I show a modal using an animation with Tailwind and react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying when I click on a modal to have an animation to show the modal but I don't achieve to do that using Tailwind and react.

Here is my code :

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Wrapper from "./Wrapper";
import Input from "./Input";

import "./styles.css";
import Button from "./Button";
import Modal from "./Modal";

function App() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const handleShowModal = useCallback(() => {
    setShowModal(!showModal);
  }, [showModal]);
  const handleCloseModal = useCallback(() => {
    setShowModal(false);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="p-4">
      <h1 className="text-red-500 text-center">PlayGround</h1>
      <Wrapper className="p-2">
        <Input />
      </Wrapper>
      <Wrapper className="p-2">
        <Button onClick={handleShowModal}>Show Modal</Button>
        {showModal && <Modal onCancel={handleCloseModal} />}
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And you can see my full code here :

[my full project](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tailwind-components-ln91r?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js:0-932)

I would like something like that :

[the goal](http://jsfiddle.net/d36x0cfn/1/)

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [headless ui](https://headlessui.dev/)

you can use like this

```js
import { Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { useState } from 'react'

function MyComponent() {
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsShowing((isShowing) => !isShowing)}>
        Toggle
      </button>
      <Transition
        show={isShowing}
        enter="transition-opacity duration-75"
        enterFrom="opacity-0"
        enterTo="opacity-100"
        leave="transition-opacity duration-150"
        leaveFrom="opacity-100"
        leaveTo="opacity-0"
      >
        I will fade in and out
      </Transition>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation sample for the modal open & close animation provided can be achieved by adding a transition on updating opacity, & Y position of modal (based on visibility of the Modal).

```
  <div className={`h-[200px] w-[500px] flex flex-col bg-white transition-all duration-1000 ease-in-out
        ${
          isVisible
            ? "!opacity-100 !translate-y-full"
            : "opacity-0 -translate-y-full "
        }`}
      >
    </div>
```

Sample link for above implementation : [preview](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/suspicious-ully-gkrq3r?file=%2Ftailwind.config.js%3A8%2C4&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9nx9s900072v6is3soobwz%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9nx9s900032v6i3ydxioge%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9nx9s900042v6iru73t2re%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9nx9s900062v6i373xa6sl%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clp9nx9s900032v6i3ydxioge%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9nx9s900032v6i3ydxioge%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clp9nx9s900062v6i373xa6sl%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9nx9s900052v6ijtkg4st6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9nx9s900062v6i373xa6sl%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clp9nx9s900052v6ijtkg4st6%2522%257D%252C%2522clp9nx9s900042v6iru73t2re%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clp9nx9s900042v6iru73t2re%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)